# how to create a reusable component in angular with different service injection?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-components, reusability

they say the component's should be reusable but I cant find out how to make my case reusable?
I want to have a component that is used to confirm something at server?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-confirm',
    template: '<button (Click)="confirm()">'

})
export class ConfirmComponent {
 constructor(private confirmService: ConfirmService){}
 confirm(){
  this.confirmService.confirm();
 }
}
```

now if I want to use it somewhere else how can I change the confirm service that is injected in to this class I know that I can define this at the component decorator so that it injects something that I want as confirmService in to this class but then this services are created for each of this components?

**edit**

when i handle dependency injection myself i would do something like this:

```
class ConfirmComponent{
 confirmService: ConfirmServiceInterface;
 constructor(confirmService: ConfirmServiceInterface){
   this.confirmService = confirmService;
 }
}
```

first use:

```
new ConfirmComponent(a);
```

second use:

```
new ConfirmComponent(b);
```

I want to know how to do this in angular?

Comment: To make it "re-usable", you'll have to override the providers. [It's all in the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection). You can do it at component level, at module level, you can even make it dynamic.

Comment: I'm using it somewhere in my application if I want to reuse it somewhere else with a different service how should i provide it so it knows here use this one and there use that one

Comment: The cleaniest way would be at module level with either factories or overriding. I've given you a link to follow, feel free to check it and see what suits you best

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is to provide the service differently depending on where you are then I would define a SuperClass that different implementations of the service inherit. Let's call it SuperClass then in the component instead of ConfirmService I inject SuperClass. Next you just provide it in different modules differently:

```
// module 1
{provide: SuperClass, useClass: ConfirmServiceImplementation}

// module 2
{provide: SuperClass, useClass: ConfirmServiceAnotherImplementation}
```